# UIImageView Tag and Tap Gesture Issue

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am working on a Kid's Book App for iPad. It has a UIView which loads UIImageView to display UIImages (JPEG's), user can swipe on images to browse through pages - everything works fine. Now I wanted to add some interactivity to some of the pages by adding another UIImageView which would load a PNG file and on Tap Gesture I want to animate them... Below is the code snippet...

I added a Tap Gesture to UIView inside viewDidLoad. viewDidLoad calls loadPage and inside loadPage I am programatically adding a UIImageView (imageAnimation) containing a PNG file and also assigning a tag to it so that I can play animations based on tags inside handleTap routine. For some reason, the switch statement in handleTap execute ONLY for case 1, for other cases handleTap routine is NEVER called. What wrong am I doing?

```
#import "KidsViewController.h"

@implementation KidsViewController
@synthesize imageAnimation;

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]] || [touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    NSLog(@"KidsViewController ==> handleTap.");

    switch (((UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer).view.tag)      
    {
        case 1:
            //...
            NSLog(@"KidsViewController ==> handleTap. Switch Case: %d", 1);
            break;
        case 2:
            //...
            NSLog(@"KidsViewController ==> handleTap. Switch Case: %d", 2);
            break;
        case 3:
            //...
            NSLog(@"KidsViewController ==> handleTap. Switch Case: %d", 3);
            break;            
        default:
            NSLog(@"KidsViewController ==> handleTap. Switch Case: DEFAULT");
            break;
    }

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    pageCount=12;
    pageNum=1;

    //put imageviews in place
    imageNext.frame=CGRectMake(0,0-crop,screenwidth,screenheight+(crop*2));
    imageCurrent.frame=CGRectMake(0,0-crop,screenwidth,screenheight+(crop*2));

    [self loadPage];

    imageCurrent.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self filePathForLanguage:language pageNumber:pageNum fileType:@"jpg"]];

    //TAP GESTURE
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;
    tapRecognizer=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                   initWithTarget:self
                   action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;
    [self.imageAnimation addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [tapRecognizer release];
}

-(void)loadPage{

    imageNext.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self filePathForLanguage:language pageNumber:pageNum fileType:@"jpg"]]; //[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathFilename];

    switch (pageNum)      
    {
        case 1:
            //...
            NSLog(@"KidsViewController ==> loadPage. Switch Case: %d", pageNum);
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"P3-stilts_00000.png"];
            CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
            imageAnimation = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
            imageAnimation.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            imageAnimation.image = image;
            imageAnimation.tag = pageNum;
            [self.view addSubview:imageAnimation];
            [image release];
            break;
        case 2:
            //...
            NSLog(@"KidsViewController ==> loadPage. Switch Case: %d", pageNum);
            imageAnimation.image = nil;
            [imageAnimation setCenter:CGPointMake(-100,-100)];
            break;
        case 3:
            //...
            NSLog(@"KidsViewController ==> loadPage. Switch Case: %d", pageNum);
            UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bug.png"];
            CGRect bugFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image3.size.width, image3.size.height);
            imageAnimation = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:bugFrame];
            imageAnimation.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            imageAnimation.image = image3;
            imageAnimation.tag = pageNum;
            [self.view addSubview:imageAnimation];
            [image3 release];
            break;            
        default:
            NSLog(@"KidsViewController ==> loadPage. Switch Case: DEFAULT");
            [imageAnimation setCenter:CGPointMake(-100,-100)];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [setupViewController release];
    [imageCurrent release];
    [imageNext release];
    [imageShadow release];
    [imageMenuBar release];
    [imageAnimation release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always get tag of your **self.view**. It's **tag** by default is **0**. So switch jumps to *default* option.

You can add your recognizer to **imageAnimation** and it will work fine.

Comment: Adding the gesture recognizer to the imageview (imageAnimation) directly does sound the easist route to go.  Your switch will work and you don't have to figure out where it came from (other than using tapRecognizer.view).

Comment: Thx Nekto & Sam, I tried adding the gesture recognizer to the imageview (imageAnimation) directly, in that case, it works ONLY for one page but does not work on other pages. Could that be because I am not releasing and adding back properly? I want to reuse imageAnimation with different PNGs and to handle different animations on many pages.

Comment: Did you assign unique tag for each page (for each  **imageAnimation.tag**)? If yes, can you post updated version of your code? Or, please, give us more details.

Comment: Nekto, I edited the code as per your suggestions, still it doen't work. For some reason, the switch statement in handleTap execute ONLY for case 1, for other cases handleTap routine is NEVER called. What wrong am I doing?

Comment: Because you have only one recognizer for only one page. Your call stack is : `pageNum=1;...[self loadPage];...case 1:...[self.imageAnimation addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];`. You are creating only one page and setting recognizer only for it. You should create individual recognizers to each page.

Comment: Thx Nekto, but I am adding recognizer to self.imageAnimation (UIImageView) and I am re-using imageAnimation in other pages.

Comment: But your **pageNum** is always **1**. What is _KidsViewController_? it contains one view? or several pages? I don't understand your view hierarchy.

Comment: pageNum gets incremented/decremented when user swipes left or right on the screen, I didn't include that code to control the length of thread. There is ONLY one ViewController which uses 3 UIImageViews (imageCurrent, imageNext, imageShadow) to swap the images (pages of book).

Comment: Then you should create 3 recognizers, not one.

Comment: That means, I should be applying a separate recognizer for each page to same imageAnimation (UIImageView)? How would it distinguish separate recognizers for same UIImageView? or do I need separate UIImageViews for each page also?

Comment: You need separate UIImageView for each page with unique tag, if i understand right. Recognizer would distinguish them by there tags.

Comment: @Alex let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2959/discussion-between-nekto-and-alex)

Comment: Thx Nekto for taking out time and helping me resolve this issue. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be here:

```
switch (((UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer).view.tag)
```

When you register that gesture recognizer you are adding to your view controller's view and not to the imageview you are after:

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

If you are trying to get the view that was tapped, consider using something like

```
CGPoint point = [tapRecognizer locationInView:tapRecognizer.view];
UIView *viewThatWasTouched = [tapRecognizer.view hitTest:point withEvent:nil];
```